# Friendly ID 4 Using scoped module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

I can't work this out.  Using the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/Scoped)

I have two models

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  has_many :pages
  friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId      
  belongs_to :region
  friendly_id :name, :use => :scoped, :scope => :region
end
```

According to the documentation this should work. But when I create a page it's not creating a slug via a scope, and this means when I create another page with the same name I get duplicate index error.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to change the db index (not exactly sure to what though). What indexes have you added when setting up FriendlyId?

Comment: Aha, I had a unique index.  I thought friendly_id added something related to the scoped model for some reason but it would appear it just checks to see if there is another Page with the same slug belonging to the region.  Thanks very much.  Do you want to put updating the index as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Glad it helped. :) I was already answering with a different suggestion, but I'm leaving both for future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are currently indexing your pages on the slug field with something like this:

```
add_index :page, :slug, :unique => true
```

then you might want to swap that for an index on both the slug and the region:

```
remove_index :page, :slug
add_index :page, [:slug, :region_id], :unique => true
```

The documentation describes how to start using `:history` and `:scoped` together in FriendlyId 5, maybe that could give you some ideas on how to solve it in your case: http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/README.md#Upgrading_from_FriendlyId_4_0

---

Or, you could just remove the uniqueness constraint, as I now see that you have replied to my original comment. :)

```
remove_index :page, :slug
add_index :page, :slug # no :unique here
```