# Wrong posts showing up in other board

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I current have my project set up like this:

```
resources :boards, :path => '' do
  resources :posts, :path => 'thread' do
    resources :replies
```

On `/board1/` only posts from `board1` show, same for `board2`. In `/board1/thread/1/` it shows `post 1` and the replies to it.
However in `/board2/thread/1/` the post that is showing is from `board1/thread/1/`, and in the reverse `board1/thread/2/` shows the post from `board2/thread/2/`.

Each post has a related `board_id` in the db, and each reply has the related  post_id in the db.

How can I keep these separate?

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :replies, through: :posts
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, :replies
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
  has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :pid, use: :slugged
  after_create :set_pid
  def set_pid
    post_max = self.board.posts.maximum(:pid)
    reply_max = self.board.replies.maximum(:pid)
    if post_max.to_i < reply_max.to_i
       self.update_attributes(:pid => reply_max.to_i + 1) 
    else
       self.update_attributes(:pid => post_max.to_i + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Code to display post in `/:board_id/show`:

```
<% @board.posts.find_each do |post| %>
<%= post.subject %>
  <%= post.name %> 
  <%= post.email %> 
  <%= post.created_at %>
  No.<%= post.pid %>
  <%= link_to "[reply]", board_posts_path(@board, @post)%>
  <br>
  <%= post.comment %><br><br>
<%= render "replies/replies" %>
<% end %>
```

Code to display post in `/:board_id/thread/:id`:

```
<p>
  <%= @post.subject %>
  <%= @post.name %>
  <%= @post.email %>
  <%= @post.created_at %>
  No.<%= @post.pid %> 
  <br>
  <%= @post.comment %>
</p>
```

**Edit:**

```
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @board = Board.friendly.find(params[:board_id])
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
    @reply = @post.replies.create(reply_params)
    redirect_to @board
  end
  private
    def reply_params
      params.require(:reply).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :comment, :pid)
    end
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @boards = Board.all
    @replies = Reply.all
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @board = Board.friendly.find(params[:board_id])
    @post = @board.posts.create(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @board
    else render @board
    end
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :comment, :pid)
    end
end
```

Comment: What should board2/thread/1 show?

Comment: @FrederickCheung if I make a post: on board2 called "post on board 2" `board2/thread/1` should show "post on board2", however it will instead show "post on board 1" unless the post on board2 was made before the post on board1, in which case it will show "post on board2"

Answer (score 2):

The missing part here is the RepliesController which is the source of the problem if I got the question correctly.

Most probably you have there something like  `@replies = current_post.replies` which fetch all replies of the given post regardless of the current board. Scoping post by board will solve the problem:

`current_post = Post.find_by(board_id: params[:board_id], id: params[:post_id])
if current_post
  @replies = current_post.replies
end`

Comment: I edited the post to have to have the RepliesController. I'm not entirely sure how to use the code you have given.

Answer (score 1):

On your `friendly_id` declaration in the Post model, you don't have the `pid` as globally unique.  Use this form of `friendly_id`, instead:

```
friendly_id :pid, use: :scoped, scope: :board
```

In this way, duplicate `friendly_id` values for `pid` are kept separate by the board that they belong to.  This is necessary for slugging nested resources properly.  The `:scoped` value says that it's for nested (scoped) models, and the `scope:` key indicates that posts is nested within boards.  Note that you may have to do this with replies, as well.

You'll also want to make sure that your indexes for your :slug are correct.  Typically when the :scope is incorrect, you'll find it when you try to save the record.  In this case, it looks like the indexes might not be set correctly to ensure the uniqueness of the board name/post pid combination.  Check out [Friendly ID 4 Using scoped module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204136/friendly-id-4-using-scoped-module) for more information.

When you have the indexes sorted out, you'll find that inserting new records will require you to have the friendly_id (based on your pid) already assigned.  You may also want to look into using slug candidates to dynamically generate the proper slug at creation time.  Also check out [slug candidates rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764036/slug-candidates-rails-4) for some usage information.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I don't think this is being caused by `friendly_id` as even with it disabled for both `board` and `post` the same issue still occurs

Comment: Without friendly_id, you would have to make sure that your `Post.find` call was changed to `Post.find_by(board_id: params[:board_id], pid: params[:post_id]`.  This issue, either with or without friendly_id is that you're not properly finding the Post records in context of the Board that they're associated with.

Comment: I've updated my post to question to include `PostsController`

Comment: With friendly_id, after you add the `:scoped` and `scope:` options, you will probably have to re-slug each model that is used in nested routing.  This is because the old slugs are still in the database, so `friendly.find` would still retrieve the same records, causing the same behavior.

Comment: ran `db:drop` and `db:migrate` again. Still happening, Looking at the db (sqlite3) the slugs are correct. I can also make 3 posts on board1 and then 1 post board2 and going to /board1/thread/4/ will show what should be /board1/thread/1/.   So it seems to be still using the post id insted of the pid for the url.

Comment: Try changing your `link_to` calls to look like this: `<%= link_to "[reply]", board_posts_path(@board, @post.pid)%>`.  Notice that they specifically say to use pid - when you just use the object @post, it implies using @post.id.  Better?

Comment: `undefined method `pid' for nil:NilClass` could the issue be that I'm using numbers for my friendly_id?

Comment: Numbers *should* be fine, but it's certainly possible that friendly_id is getting confused.  I recall there being an option to not allow routing by `id` when numbers are used, but I can't seem to find a reference.